# How to overload the ++ operator for a enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading, pre-increment

This is what I tried, but I see that overloading only increments the variable if I assign it to another variable.  I.e, The value of the variable on which I do the increment does not increase.  So, in the example below variable `newDay` is THU but `currentDay` remains WED.

How do I define the overload operator to increment variable I am doing the operation on?

```
typedef enum days {MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN} days;

inline days operator++ (days& d) {
    return static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   days currentDay = WED;
   days newDay = ++currentDay;
   cout << "Current day: " << currentDay << ", Stored day: " << calendar[0] << ", New day: " << newDay << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7` to increment something, and what it that something?

Comment: `typedef enum days {...} days;` is an exercise in redundancy. Just define `enum days {...};`. C++ doesn't require the same acrobatics as C to introduce the enum as a type.

Comment: Consider using [scoped enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I modify your overloaded operator to this:

```
inline days operator++ (days const& d) {
    return static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7);
}
```

It still compiles, despite the fact I added a `const` specifier there. That's because you *are not modifying `d`* like the semantics of prefix `++` demand.

So make sure you do modify it, if you want the operator to have the desired effect:

```
inline days operator++ (days& d) {
    d = static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7);
    return d;
}
```

---

Without commenting on the validity of your own design, note that it is a widely held opinion that prefix `operator++` should return a modifiable lvalue, like the built-ins do. Bear in mind if you find yourself writing code like `++x = y`, you need to return a reference, i.e. `date& operator++(date&)`.

Comment: Just be aware that the modulo operator is very slow. Increasing the value and comparing to the maximum is much faster.

Answer (score -1):

You defined the postfix operator. The normal behavior of the postfix operator is to increment the value of its argument but return the original value. It should behave like this:

```
days operator++(days& d,int){
    days temp=d;
    d=static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7);
    return temp;
}
```

What you want is the prefix operator. This increments the value of the argument and returns a reference to its arguments. It should look like this:

```
days& operator++(days& d){
    d=static_cast<days>((static_cast<int>(d) + 1) % 7);
    return d;
}
```